# Circuit Diagram in Tex with OTE and PILOT Light Symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I want to create a circuit diagram in TeXstudio or LaTeX that contains 2 switch, 2 capacitor, an OTE symbol and a Pilot Light symbol.

I am attaching the snip of the required diagram.

I also want to know that is there any tools available using which I can convert an image file into a LaTeX code.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You might want to have a look at the [`circuitikz` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz). Please try to write some code and post a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) of specific issues you can't deal with. Indeed, your question falls in the 'do it for me' category and is not a reasonable question to ask on this website.

Comment: This could be done with a mix of `circuitikz` and plain Ti*k*Z, given that the former has no symbols similar to the "(out)" and the "PL" (but it's not difficult to build them). And no, there is not a straightforward way to convert a generic image to LaTeX code, but you can always import the image and use it if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt using `TikZ` and `Circuitikz` as suggested by @Rmano.

- `Circuitikz` package is used only to add capacitor elements, it loads `TikZ` package.
- `arrows.meta` library is used to create OUT element.
- `shapes` library is used to add cross shape to the PL element.

Here is the corresponding code (not an optimized version):

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,shapes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\ctikzset{
capacitors/scale=0.7,
capacitors/thickness=0.8,
 }
\draw (-4.5,2.5) node[above]{$L_1$} -- ++(0,-5);
\draw (-4.5,2.2) -- ++(0.75,0)node{$\bullet$} -- ++(45:0.5) node[midway,below=0.2cm]{$I/1$}
++(0.1,-0.353)node{$\bullet$} -- ++(0.25,0) edge[dashed] ++(0.5,0)++(0.5,0.3) -- ++(0,-5)node[midway](a){};

\draw (-4.5,0) -- ++(0.75,0)node{$\bullet$} -- ++(45:0.5) node[midway,below=0.2cm]{$I/2$}
++(0.1,-0.353)node{$\bullet$} -- ++(0.25,0) edge[dashed] (a.center);

\draw (a.center) to[C,l=$I/1$] ++(2,0)to[C,l=$I/2$] ++(1.5,0) coordinate(b); 
\draw [-{Parenthesis[reversed,scale=3]}] (b) -- ++(0.25,0) node[right=-0.2cm]{OUT} node[above right=0.2cm and -0.1cm]{$O/2$} ;

\draw [{Parenthesis[reversed,scale=3]}-] (b)++(0.9,0) -- ++(0.75,0) coordinate(c);

\draw (c) -- ++(0,2.5)
(c) -- ++(0,-2.5)
(c) -- ++(1.95,0) coordinate(d)
-- ++ (0,2.5) node[above]{$L_2$} 
(d) -- ++(0,-2.5);

\path (c) -- (d) node[midway,cross out,draw,minimum size=0.8cm]{};
\path (c) -- (d) node[midway,circle,draw,fill=white](PL){PL};

\draw[dotted,white] (c) -- ++(0.25,0);

\node at (-3.55,3.25){Input};
\node at (3.55,3.25){Output};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which yields:
[image]

Comment: Nice, I like the `edge` trick!